# Do I confront my boss

Tags: employer-relations

My coworker fairly often does not communicate important information to me. Office secretary witnesses this first-hand today and says to me,

> Now I see what's going on, [Coworker] is not telling you what you need to know.  Then, secretary goes on to tell me that boss always looks to blame me.

My Boss knows that my coworker can be inept, but favors him.

Do I go to my boss about what the secretary said?  Boss was supposed to bring me and coworker for daily meetings, and never made it happen.

I tried suggestions made before.  Not working well.

Comment: You already asked this question 1.5 months ago, did you try out some of the suggestions that were offered?

Comment: Yes.  Things go well for a couple weeks, then right back to dysfunction (with coworker).

Comment: Then its out of your hands. If your boss is aware of the situation, and the secretary is aware, document the conversations you have and move on. If things break downstream, then you have a record of when it was discussed.

Comment: Ok.   Interestingly boss' s boss made a rare visit during my conversation with secretary.  He saw I was upset and asked what was going on.  I just told him I was frustrated with continued lack of communication.   He said he'd speak to my boss today.  Little scared she'll retaliate.  Thanks.

Comment: You've raised this issue to your boss. Your boss has decided (to not do anything apparently) . Now your boss' boss is aware of the situation and will talk with your boss. The first question I presume that will be asked is "Did [Cantstartover] tell you of this issue with [Coworker]?" If the answer is "Yes", then it is literally out of your hands. You've done your due diligence in informing management of this communication issue.

Answer (score 0):

What the secretary said might not be relevant at all. She/he has different duties and responsibilities than you and your coworker, she might not understand technical aspects that the two of you do.

With this said, inter-team communication is handled by you, your coworker, and your boss. State the situation objectively and directly,

> Mistakes are made when communication fails, I would like to meet with coworker more often to resolve issues before they happen.

Don't partake in gossip.

Comment: Secretary knows a lot actually.  I have tried to get coworker to communicate with me more.  It goes ok for a bit then deteriorates.

Comment: @Cantstartover Do you have the impression that this is on purpose or is it just the way that person (coworker) is?